# Material UI change opacity of background when Drawer is open

Tags: material-ui

I would like to know how to set another background color and change the opacity of the background when the Material UI drawer is opened. I didn't find something about this in the docs. I'm using React and TS.

Answer (score 4):

This will solve your problem:

```
        <Drawer BackdropProps={{style:{backgroundColor:"red", opacity:2}}}>
        </Drawer
```

Comment: backdropprops deprecated in latest mui

Comment: Use `slotProps.backdrop` instead.